# I can not localize my XCode Project ? Says Project has not been localized

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I am currently trying to localize my Project but it doesnt work.
I simply want to add a new language to it but i can not choose any resource.
If i try to localize a specific resource i got a message like "You have to localize your Project first"

I am stuck and i have no clue what to do ?

Any ideas ?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other solutions didn't work for me so I ended up solving this by editing the project.pbxproj file in textedit.  Change `knownRegions` from an empty list to include `en` and `Base`:

```
        knownRegions = (
            en,
            Base,
        );
```

Now I can add languages and it doesn't complain that the project isn't localized.

I wasn't able to localize the project because none of the resources appeared in the list and I couldn't add resources to the list because the project wasn't localized.  Catch 22. (this is with Xcode 6.2)

Comment: same in xcode9.4.1... If you see 0 localized files don't forget to do following! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266169/0-localized-files-seen-in-xcode-for-native-development-language

Comment: Wow!! Super Nice. Thanks!!