# 0 localized files seen in xcode for native development language

Tags: ios, localization

I'm working on a project where I need to add localize file of another language in xcode.

But when I try to add new language, it does not show me list of the base storyboards. Like given below

[image]

Also I'm seeing that `0 files localized` for english - development language.

[image]

Anyone having any idea about it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should localize files you need, then those files will be present in list of localizable resources

[image]