# Cannot add localization in Xcode - Spritebuilder project

Tags: xcode, localization, spritebuilder

I have finished my first game project with Spritebuilder and its time for localisation. But, when I try to add a new localisation, even though I follow all the correct steps, no language is added in Xcode and no localised project folder are created after I click finish (see attached photo).

Hint: If I try to add the language again the list with the resource files is empty...

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is a Spritebuilder bug. I have tested it again, by publishing a blank project from Spritebuilder 1.3.3 and the problem replicates. I have no problem creating localisations to a project that was created within XCode

Comment: SpriteBuilder provides its own means of adding languages and localizing labels, perhaps that is in conflict with xcode localization?

Comment: Yes, sprite builder has its own localisation system, but there is text and images in the source code & Xcode, that has to be handled by Xcode for localisation, right? How to you handle that? And how will apple recognise the project as multilingual, if you don't follow their methods of localisation?

Comment: ΟΚ, Ι have found out that translations made in Sprite Builder's Language Editor are used properly by the Project, meaning that if my phone is set in a translated locale, the language of the game appears in the translated language. I am going to try using CCBLocalize instead of NSLocalizedString, to see if I can localise source code strings as well, using the Language Editor

Comment: If I use CCBLocalize instead of NSLocalizedString in my source, and I add manually the key to the Language Editor, it works! Two questions: 1. Can I use something like genstring to automatically import the keys to language editor? 2. How can I handle the localisation of images used in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue with SpriteBuilder, if you prefer Xcode's string format. Try this answer to restore this capability

[I deleted the Localizations in Xcode, then I cannot add any Localizations back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623783/i-deleted-the-localizations-in-xcode-then-i-cannot-add-any-localizations-back)